# Can't locate element on Microsoft Sign In page

Tags: python, selenium, element

I'm currently trying to locate Microsoft Sign In page's email input box by using xpath (others as well) but after many tries I still can't locate the correct element for it.

After copying the element from the page, this is the element given:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email, phone, or Skype" aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" data-bind="
                                    hasFocus: focus,
                                    textInput: email,
                                    attr: {'placeholder': config.text.emailPlaceHolder, 'aria-invalid': !error}">
```

And this is currently my python code:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control']")
login.send_keys(config.username)
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I had tried multiple times but I still can't get the proper element to proceed. After entering https://forms.office.com/ I had successfully captured the sign in element but stuck at the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='landing-signin-hrd' and @id='hrdIframe']")))
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @placeholder='Email, phone, or Skype']")))
    login.send_keys("StrangerSphinx")
    login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    ```
  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.landing-signin-hrd#hrdIframe")))
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control[placeholder='Email, phone, or Skype']")))
    login.send_keys("StrangerSphinx")
    login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)